# Group by with text and date time combination

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
id  col1    col2    namecol1    datetime1           teamcol1  namecol2  datetime2
1   12345   2345    name1   2014-10-13 11:57:24.713 teama       
2   12345   2345    name1   2014-10-13 11:57:24.713 teamb     abc       2014-11-29 09:55:38.533
3   12345   2345    name1   2014-10-13 11:57:24.713 teamb     bcd       2014-12-02 06:35:38.917
4   12345   2345    name1   2014-10-13 11:57:24.713 teamc     def       2014-12-22 11:57:54.863
5   12345   2345    name1   2014-10-13 11:57:24.713 teamd     efg       2015-01-03 13:28:24.717
```

I need this output:

```
col1    col2    Team1   DateTime1            Team2      DateTime2                   Team3   DateTime3
12345   2345    bcd 2014-12-02 06:35:38.917  def        2014-12-22 11:57:54.863     efg     2015-01-03 13:28:24.717
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN teamcol1='teamb' THEN namecol2 END) AS Team1, 
    CONVERT(DATE, MAX(CASE WHEN teamcol1='teamb' THEN datetime2 END), 105) AS DateTime1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN teamcol1='teamc' THEN namecol2 END) AS PRECON_AUDIT, 
    CONVERT(DATE,MAX(CASE WHEN teamcol1='teamc' THEN datetime2 END), 105) AS DateTime2, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN teamcol1 IN ('teamd') THEN namecol2 END) AS Team3, 
    CONVERT(DATE,MAX(CASE WHEN teamcol1 IN ('teamd') THEN datetime2 END),105) AS DateTime3, 
    col1, col2 
FROM 
    (SELECT *  
     FROM table1) Z
WHERE  
    col1 = '12345' 
GROUP BY 
    col1, col2
```

Output of this query:

```
col1    col2    Team1   DateTime1               Team2   DateTime2               Team3   DateTime3
12345   2345    abc     2014-12-02 06:35:38.917  def    2014-12-22 11:57:54.863  efg    2015-01-03 13:28:24.717
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]
*Table1 is like audit table which will have multiple entries with different combination of col1,col2.
I need to display for each combination of col1,col2 different team names and with appropriate namecol2 and datetime2 columns.
When i use the query mentioned above it is giving me the output correctly if there is no repetition in teamcol1. If there is a repetition in teamcol1 (as mentioned in question) it is giving me the wrong namecol2.
In case of repetition in teamcol1 i need latest namecol2 and datetime2 ( from the table i need namecol2 -- bcd and datetime2 -- 2014-12-02 06:35:38.917)*

Comment: You need to explain some logic for your desired output. I can make a query that extracts that easily - - but whether it'll work for you is impossible to know because you have not mentioned anything about how it should work.

Comment: sorry for not explaining. added explanation now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first make a list of all groups (`DISTINCT` col1, col2).

Then for each group find one row with the latest `datetime2`. Do it three times, for each `teamb`, `teamc`, `teamd`.

You can put complex query inside `OUTER APPLY` with whatever logic and ordering you need.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int, col1 int, col2 int, namecol1 varchar(255), [datetime1] datetime, teamcol1 varchar(255), namecol2 varchar(255), [datetime2] datetime);

INSERT INTO @T (id, col1, col2, namecol1, datetime1, teamcol1, namecol2, datetime2) VALUES (1, 12345, 2345, 'name1', '2014-10-13 11:57:24.713', 'teama', NULL,   NULL);
INSERT INTO @T (id, col1, col2, namecol1, datetime1, teamcol1, namecol2, datetime2) VALUES (2, 12345, 2345, 'name1', '2014-10-13 11:57:24.713', 'teamb', 'abc', '2014-11-29 09:55:38.533');
INSERT INTO @T (id, col1, col2, namecol1, datetime1, teamcol1, namecol2, datetime2) VALUES (3, 12345, 2345, 'name1', '2014-10-13 11:57:24.713', 'teamb', 'bcd', '2014-12-02 06:35:38.917');
INSERT INTO @T (id, col1, col2, namecol1, datetime1, teamcol1, namecol2, datetime2) VALUES (4, 12345, 2345, 'name1', '2014-10-13 11:57:24.713', 'teamc', 'def', '2014-12-22 11:57:54.863');
INSERT INTO @T (id, col1, col2, namecol1, datetime1, teamcol1, namecol2, datetime2) VALUES (5, 12345, 2345, 'name1', '2014-10-13 11:57:24.713', 'teamd', 'efg', '2015-01-03 13:28:24.717');

WITH
CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
    FROM @T
)
SELECT *
FROM
    CTE_Groups
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            TT.namecol2 AS Team1
            , TT.[datetime2] AS DateTime1
        FROM @T AS TT
        WHERE
            TT.teamcol1 = 'teamb'
            AND TT.col1 = CTE_Groups.col1
            AND TT.col2 = CTE_Groups.col2
        ORDER BY TT.[datetime2] DESC
    ) OA_teamb
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            TT.namecol2 AS Team2
            , TT.[datetime2] AS DateTime2
        FROM @T AS TT
        WHERE
            TT.teamcol1 = 'teamc'
            AND TT.col1 = CTE_Groups.col1
            AND TT.col2 = CTE_Groups.col2
        ORDER BY TT.[datetime2] DESC
    ) OA_teamc
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            TT.namecol2 AS Team3
            , TT.[datetime2] AS DateTime3
        FROM @T AS TT
        WHERE
            TT.teamcol1 = 'teamd'
            AND TT.col1 = CTE_Groups.col1
            AND TT.col2 = CTE_Groups.col2
        ORDER BY TT.[datetime2] DESC
    ) OA_teamd
```

Result set:

```
col1     col2    Team1    DateTime1                  Team2    DateTime2                  Team3    DateTime3
12345    2345    bcd      2014-12-02 06:35:38.917    def      2014-12-22 11:57:54.863    efg      2015-01-03 13:28:24.717
```

If there is no `teamb` for a certain combination of `col1` and `col2`, there will be `NULL`s in `Team1` and `DateTime1`. Same for `teamc` and `teamd`.